# Trim inner blanks in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

How do you trim whitespaces in teradata? Do I need to write a procedure for it?

Comment: What do you mean by **inner blanks**?. Any example ?

Comment: What separates the words in this sentence are inner blanks.

Comment: Never know that thank you..

Comment: @D.Loo You just made my day. Edited the post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OREPLACE` can be installed in releases prior to TD 14.x as a UDF from Teradata Dev Exchange, it appeared as a native function around TD 14.0 or TD 14.10:

```
SELECT OREPLACE(colA, ' ', ''); -- Replace all whitespace, leading and trailing included
```

or you can use REGEX_REPLACE, if supported by your release of Teradata:

```
SELECT REGEX_REPLACE(colA, '[@\s+]', '', 1, 0, 'i');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trick using `replace()` for this . . .

```
select replace(replace(replace(col, ' ', '<>'), '><', ''), '<>', ' ')
```

This will take a string such as `'a   b'` and then produce:

- a<><><>b
- a<>b
- a b

Note:  It will also reduce multiple spaces at the beginning and end to a single space.  Your question doesn't specify what to do in that case.